# How to know if data comes from measurement protocol?

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

How do you recognize measurement protocol data transfer in GA?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what the [data source field in the measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ds) is for

[image]